# Woocommerce: help replacing html output

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

My checkout-billing-fields and shipping-fields are output in html with 3 different row alignements. first, last and wide. I only want to set them to be first, and last - so that each input is next to the other.

Original:

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">

    <h3>Faktureringsdetaljer</h3>




    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field"><label for="billing_first_name" class="">Fornavn <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required" id="billing_last_name_field"><label for="billing_last_name" class="">Etternavn <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value=""></p><div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide" id="billing_company_field"><label for="billing_company" class="">Navn på firma</label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_company" id="billing_company" placeholder="" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required" id="billing_address_1_field"><label for="billing_address_1" class="">Adresse <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" placeholder="Gateadresse" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required validate-postcode" id="billing_postcode_field"><label for="billing_postcode" class="">Postnummer  <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="Postnummer " value=""></p><div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-wide address-field validate-required" id="billing_city_field"><label for="billing_city" class="">Sted <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_city" id="billing_city" placeholder="Sted" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first address-field validate-state" id="billing_state_field" style="display: none"><label for="billing_state" class="">Delstat / Fylke</label><input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="billing_state" id="billing_state" value="" placeholder=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field"><label for="billing_email" class="">Epostadresse <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="kreegah@gmail.com"></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone" id="billing_phone_field"><label for="billing_phone" class="">Telefon <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value=""></p><div class="clear"></div>


</div>
```

What I want:

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">

    <h3>Faktureringsdetaljer</h3>




    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field"><label for="billing_first_name" class="">Fornavn <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required" id="billing_last_name_field"><label for="billing_last_name" class="">Etternavn <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first" id="billing_company_field"><label for="billing_company" class="">Navn på firma</label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_company" id="billing_company" placeholder="" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required" id="billing_address_1_field"><label for="billing_address_1" class="">Adresse <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" placeholder="Gateadresse" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first address-field validate-required validate-postcode" id="billing_postcode_field"><label for="billing_postcode" class="">Postnummer  <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="Postnummer " value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required" id="billing_city_field"><label for="billing_city" class="">Sted <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_city" id="billing_city" placeholder="Sted" value=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first address-field validate-state" id="billing_state_field" style="display: none"><label for="billing_state" class="">Delstat / Fylke</label><input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="billing_state" id="billing_state" value="" placeholder=""></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-first validate-required validate-email" id="billing_email_field"><label for="billing_email" class="">Epostadresse <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="email" class="input-text " name="billing_email" id="billing_email" placeholder="" value="kreegah@gmail.com"></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone" id="billing_phone_field"><label for="billing_phone" class="">Telefon <abbr class="required" title="påkrevet">*</abbr></label><input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" placeholder="" value=""></p><div class="clear"></div>


</div>
```

Anyone know where I can override these? I've been searching up and down in most of the /includes in the woocommerce folders. haven't got a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you specify exactly what you want to change? It's quite hard to compare and spot the difference.

If you only want the change the classes on some of the fields, the right way to do that is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-first');
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-first', 'address-field', 'validate-required');
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-first', 'address-field', 'validate-required');
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-last', 'address-field', 'validate-required');
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-first', 'address-field', 'validate-state');
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-first', 'address-field', 'validate-email');
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row', 'form-row', 'form-row-last', 'address-field', 'validate-phone');
    return $fields;
}
```

You should absolutely not use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Thanks @Pelmered - Just what I needed.
one small hiccup is the `<div class="clear"></div>` that also outputs right after `['billing_postcode']`. 
How do I remove this?

Comment: Ah, just add `$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['clear'] = ''`

Comment: For more modifications just var_dump the `$fields` to get an idea of what you should change to obtain the desired changes. It's actually quite straight forward when you read the output.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it out @Pelmered. 
just added the `$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['clear'] = '';`

Comment: That's a really straight forward hooked in function as $fields is passed via the filter, however, on my own case, I've noticed it only changes the class names for the html element which wrap the fields itself.I mean, for an organizational purpose, that works great, but what if I want to change the various classes which are set for all the input types within the form. I'm trying to implement a .js validation plugin which requires these custom classes to exist for labels, text, radio, checkbox, select and all types of form inputs.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to completely change the html output of those forms without changing the WooCommerce default ids and class names, so that one could at least wrap the inputs with new html elements to comply the theme's html structure. My theme uses Bootstrap graciously, however, WooCommerce forms are a complete disaster.

Comment: That is not as easy to do. Isn't it possible to adjust you JS/jQuery selectors to make it work with your custom validation?
For example: `$('.my-class-name input')`

Comment: If that's not an option you have to edit in the templates. `checkout/form-billing.php` and `checkout/form-shipping.php` is the templates you need to edit, but that would probably be rather messy and would probably break compatibility with a lot plugins if you are not very careful.

Answer (score 1):

Add these class seems to be added dynamically by the theme or a plugin its hard to trace the root file for the cause of adding these class.

In order to change the classes you need to use jQuery as the last resort.And luckily there are ids for each field so you can select specific elements and change their properties.

Here is a code which might help you.

```
jQuery("#billing_company_field").removeClass( "form-row-wide" ).addClass( "form-row-first" );
```

The above code will change class for only one div element. Use,Modify and add the other needed code. This code should be enqueued on the page where you need the changes to be affected.

Comment: Yes, this is really the last resort. But in this case, it is very easy to change this in the right way.